# Sequence contains no elements, Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.WcfClientExtension.ObtainServiceContract

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services, castle-windsor, caliburn.micro

I am working in .NET4.5 WPF application. I am getting peculiar exception that is being shown in `App.xml` on line `<desktop1:ReactiveBootstrapper x:Key="bootstrapper" />`, I think it's related to adding new web service methods.

**App.xml**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <desktop1:ReactiveBootstrapper x:Key="bootstrapper" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Utilities/Styles/DefaultStyle.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Utilities/Styles/DataGridStyle.xaml" />
            <!--<ResourceDictionary Source="Utilities/Styles/ScrollViewerStyle.xaml"/>-->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Utilities/Styles/RoundedButtonStyle.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Utilities/Styles/ExpanderStyle.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Utilities/Styles/RadioButtonStyle.xaml" />
            <!--<ResourceDictionary Source="Utilities/Styles/DropDownStyle.xaml"/>-->
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVis" />
        <iValueConverters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="negatedBoolToVis" True="Collapsed" False="Visible" />
        <iValueConverters:NullToVisibilityConverter x:Key="nullToVis" VisibleWhenNull="True" />
        <valueConverters1:NotNullToVisibilityConverter x:Key="notNullToVis" VisibleWhenNotNull="True" />
        <valueConverters1:NotNullToCollapsedVisibilityConverter x:Key="notNullToCollapsedVis"
                                                                VisibleWhenNotNull="True" />
        <valueConverters1:EnvironmentToBooleanConverter x:Key="EnvironmentToBooleanConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at Corp.Desktop.App.InitializeComponent() in c:\dev\CCTech Main\Corp-Wills\Corp.Conveyancing.Desktop\App.xaml:line 1
   at Corp.Desktop.App.Main() in c:\dev\CCTech Main\Corp-Wills\Corp.Conveyancing.Desktop\obj\x86\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

**inner stackTrace:**

```
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.WcfClientExtension.ObtainServiceContract(ComponentModel model, IWcfClientModel clientModel) in d:\work\8dfeb153df23a288\src\Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration\Client\WcfClientExtension.cs:line 239
   at Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.WcfClientExtension.ResolveClientModel(ComponentModel model) in d:\work\8dfeb153df23a288\src\Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration\Client\WcfClientExtension.cs:line 231
   at Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.WcfClientExtension.Kernel_ComponentModelCreated(ComponentModel model) in d:\work\8dfeb153df23a288\src\Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration\Client\WcfClientExtension.cs:line 189
   at Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentModelDelegate.Invoke(ComponentModel model)
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.RaiseComponentModelCreated(ComponentModel model) in d:\work\8dfeb153df23a288\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\DefaultKernel_Events.cs:line 72
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.CreateHandler(ComponentModel model) in d:\work\8dfeb153df23a288\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\DefaultKernel.cs:line 273
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.AddCustomComponent(ComponentModel model) in d:\work\8dfeb153df23a288\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\DefaultKernel.cs:line 260
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.ComponentRegistration`1.Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.IRegistration.Register(IKernelInternal kernel) in d:\work\8dfeb153df23a288\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\Registration\ComponentRegistration.cs:line 1122
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Register(IRegistration[] registrations) in d:\work\8dfeb153df23a288\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\DefaultKernel.cs:line 501
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.BasedOnDescriptor.TryRegister(Type type, IKernel kernel) in d:\work\8dfeb153df23a288\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\Registration\BasedOnDescriptor.cs:line 512
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.FromDescriptor.Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.IRegistration.Register(IKernelInternal kernel) in d:\work\8dfeb153df23a288\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\Registration\FromDescriptor.cs:line 184
   at Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.BasedOnDescriptor.Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.IRegistration.Register(IKernelInternal kernel) in d:\work\8dfeb153df23a288\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\Registration\BasedOnDescriptor.cs:line 558
   at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Register(IRegistration[] registrations) in d:\work\8dfeb153df23a288\src\Castle.Windsor\MicroKernel\DefaultKernel.cs:line 501
   at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Register(IRegistration[] registrations) in d:\work\8dfeb153df23a288\src\Castle.Windsor\Windsor\WindsorContainer.cs:line 483
   at Corp.Desktop.ReactiveBootstrapper.RegisterWcfServices() in c:\dev\CCTech Main\Corp-Wills\Corp.Conveyancing.Desktop\ReactiveBootstrapper.cs:line 101
   at Corp.Desktop.ReactiveBootstrapper.Configure() in c:\dev\CCTech Main\Corp-Wills\Corp.Conveyancing.Desktop\ReactiveBootstrapper.cs:line 146
   at Caliburn.Micro.BootstrapperBase.StartRuntime() in c:\Projects\caliburnmicro\src\Caliburn.Micro.Silverlight\Bootstrapper.cs:line 98
   at Caliburn.Micro.BootstrapperBase.Start() in c:\Projects\caliburnmicro\src\Caliburn.Micro.Silverlight\Bootstrapper.cs:line 49
   at Corp.Desktop.ReactiveBootstrapper..ctor() in c:\dev\CCTech Main\Corp-Wills\Corp.Conveyancing.Desktop\ReactiveBootstrapper.cs:line 66
```

it blows up in Reactive bootstrapper constructor on `this.Start();` I cannot step in any further.

```
 public class ReactiveBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase {
 public ReactiveBootstrapper()
    {
        this.Log.Info("Starting bootstrapper");
        this.Start();
    }
}
```

`BootstrapperBase` is from `Caliburn.Micro` I am assuming that something blew up with dependency injection.

**Has any of you stumbled upon this error before and knows what's going on here? Or has ideas how to progress with debugging any further?**, I believe exception started appearing after adding additional methods to web services but I am not 100% certain. If you need more info just ask.

Comment: *Sequence contains no elements* this means some IEnumerable/collection is empty while it should not be so. This kind of exception is also thrown when you use `First()` on an empty IEnumerable. Although I'm not familiar with other involved code here.

Comment: @KingKing In this case it was `Single()` as you can see from stack trace at the top of inner StarckTrace, thanks anyway. I am getting a bit desperate here so any kind of help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be me adding Interface that didn't have backing web-service to 'wrong' folder where all the Web service interfaces were held.

```
public static void RegisterWcfServices()
  {
        Container.Register(
            Types.FromAssemblyContaining<ITransactionService>()
                .InSameNamespaceAs<ITransactionService>()
                .Configure(
                    x =>
                    x.Named(x.Implementation.Name)
                        .AsWcfClient(
                            new DefaultClientModel
                                {
                                    Endpoint =
                                        WcfEndpoint.BoundTo(new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport) { MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue })
                                        .At(string.Format("https://{0}/{1}.svc", GetServerName(), x.Name.Substring(1)))
                                })
                        .IsFallback()));
    }
```

mechanism above then picked up the interface and since there was no WebService backing it blew up.